# Foreach loop inside an array_merge

Tags: php, users, array

I need to get a list of users display names in a dropdown menu. I have the query right, but I'm not sure how exactly to get my user foreach inside of an array.

Here is the code I need to inject the users into:

```
$data['settings']['advanced_options'] = array_merge($data['settings']['advanced_options'], [
    [
        "label"      => "Dynamic Option 1", // This is field label
        "value"      => "Dynamic Option 1", // This is field value
    ]

]);
```

My users are currently inside of this array:

```
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
  $users[] = $user->display_name;
}
```

How can I get the users inside of the array? The label and value need to be the same as `$user->display_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someting like this?

```
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
  $users[] = array(
            'label' => $user->display_name,
            'value' => $user->display_name
            );
}
```

Then do the array_merge with $users

Comment: So I have this now: $data['settings']['advanced_options'] = array_merge($data['settings']['advanced_options'], [
      [$users]
    ]);  But it's throwing an error...not sure I did it right

Comment: Is just $users, not [[$users]]

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much